# Replace lifter without removing heads or engine in 2000 Mustang?

Tags: engine, ford, mustang, valve-lifter

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-9dFdGq-vI I don't see why it wouldn't work as long as I torque everything down correctly and put it back together correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a generic sense, yes, you can remove the lifters without removing the heads or engine from the vehicle. I'm assuming your engine is the 3.8L V6. There were two other engines available, the 4.6L V8 and 5.4L V8. Both of these are overhead cam engines which used rocker on lifter arrangements. I'll assume you don't have these because most owners of these engines because these would be in the GT (4.6L 3 valve per cylinder head) and Cobra SVT (5.4L 4 valve per cylinder head) would speak up about their particular vehicle type.

As for the 3.8L, you'd need to pull the intake manifold from the engine, then remove the rockers and the lifters should be right there for you.